# How to assign gsutil path to a variable

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I'm writing a script to automate db backup.
For gsutil to work on bash script, you need to give a full path e.g;
*/home/user/google-cloud-sdk-358.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil cp ....*

Now I want to set the value of **which gsutil** to a var but it prints blank line. I suspect it the characters that form the path.
This was the expected output (/home/user/google-cloud-sdk-358.0.0-linux-x86_64/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil)

**Also:** Suggestion to the best approach of doing periodic backup of db from gcloud vm to storage bucket is welcomed.

```
g_util=$(which gsutil)
pw=$(pwd)
g_s=$(which gs)

echo $g_util  #prints a blank line
echo $g_s
echo $pwd
```

Comment: The command that you are using will work. However, you are leaving out context on how you are running the commands and exporting the variables. Edit your question with details. Read this link on how to export variables:  https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-variables-export

Comment: Are you sure that `which gsutil` actually prints that full path? Even when run in the script's context (which may have a different `PATH` from your normal interactive shell)?